# A quick way to determine interval of convergence for power series

Tags: calculus, power-series

I would start with an example..

> Consider the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)(x-2)^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}$$
>
> Determine the interval of convergence of this power series. If the interval
> is bounded, be sure to determine whether the series converges at the endpoints.

---

Apply Ratio Test

$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\left|\frac{\frac{(n+5)(x-2)^{n+1}}{7^{n+1}((n+1)^2+11)}}{\frac{(n+4)(x-2)^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}}\right|=\left|\frac{7^n(n^2+11)(n+5)(x-2)^{n+1}}{7^{n+1}((n+1)^2+11)(n+4)(x-2)^n}\right|=\left|\frac{(n^2+11)(n+5)(x-2)}{7(n^2+2n+12)(n+4)}\right|$$

And take the limit we have:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n^2+11)(n+5)(x-2)}{7(n^2+2n+12)(n+4)}\right|=\left|\frac{x-2}{7}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n^2+11)(n+5)}{(n^2+2n+12)(n+4)}\right|$$

Since $\forall x>0,\frac{(n^2+11)(n+5)}{(n^2+2n+12)(n+4)}>0$ that
$$\left|\frac{x-2}{7}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{(n^2+11)(n+5)}{(n^2+2n+12)(n+4)}\right|=
\left|\frac{x-2}{7}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n^2+11)(n+5)}{(n^2+2n+12)(n+4)}$$
$$=\left|\frac{x-2}{7}\right|\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2(1+\frac{11}{n^2})n(1+\frac{5}{n})}{n^2(1+\frac{2}{n}+\frac{12}{n^2})n(1+\frac{4}{n})}$$
$$=\left|\frac{x-2}{7}\right|(1)=L$$

By ratio test $L<1\rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)(x-2)^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}$ converges
$$\left|\frac{x-2}{7}\right|(1)<1$$
$$\left|\frac{x}{7}-\frac{2}{7}\right|<1$$
$$\frac{2}{7}-1<\frac{x}{7}<\frac{2}{7}+1$$
$$2-7<x<2+7$$
$$-5<x<9$$

Then we check the endpoints

When $x=5$ we have:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)(-7)^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}
=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)(-1)^n}{n^2+11}$$

Also $\forall n>0,\frac{(n+4)}{n^2+11}$ is decreasing

And $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(n+4)}{n^2+11}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{(1+\frac{4}{n})}{n(1+\frac{11}{n^2})}=0$$

Therefore by Alternating series test we can conclude that the series converges.

When $x=9$

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)(7)^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+4}{n^2+11}$$

Recall that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ diverges

And $$\frac{\frac{n}{n^2+11}}{\frac{1}{n}}=\frac{n^2}{n^2+11}=\frac{n^2}{n^2(1+\frac{11}{n^2})}=1$$

By Limit Comparison Test we have:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2+11}\text{ is divergent}$$

Since $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n}{n^2+11}\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+4}{n^2+11}$$

By Basic comparison Test that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n+4}{n^2+11}\text{is divergent}$$

Therefore the interval of convergence is $-5\le x<9$

> Finally I got the interval..normally, this is how I do this kind of questions, but sometimes in exam, the questions don't ask for steps.. so I just wondering if there is any quick way to determine interval of convergence for power series

---

What I guessed so far..

A power serie centered at $c$ defined as following:
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n\left(x-c\right)^n$$
$1.$If $a_n=1$ have
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(x-c\right)^n\text{ which converges on } (c-1,c+1)$$
$2.$If $a_n=\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n$ where $a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge a\neq0$ we have
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n\left(x-c\right)^n\text{ which converges on } (c-a,c+a)$$
$3.$If $a_n=n^{b}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}\wedge a\neq0$ we have
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:n^{b}\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n\left(x-c\right)^n\text{ which converges on }\left\{\begin{array}{l}
(c-a,c+a),a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge b\ge0
\\ [c-a,c+a),a>0\wedge -1\le b<0
\\ (c-a,c+a],a<0\wedge -1\le b<0
\\ [c-a,c+a],a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge b<-1\end{array}\right.$$
$4.$If $a_n=j^{n^k}n^b\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n$ where $a,b,j,k\in\mathbb{R}\wedge a\neq0$ we have
$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:j^{n^k}n^b\left(\frac{1}{a}\right)^n\left(x-c\right)^n\text{ which converges on }
\left\{\begin{array}{l}(
\frac{cj-a}{j},\frac{cj+a}{j}),a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge b\ge0\wedge k=1 \wedge j\neq0
\\ [\frac{cj-a}{j},\frac{cj+a}{j}),a>0\wedge -1\le b<0\wedge k=1 \wedge j\neq0
\\ (\frac{cj-a}{j},\frac{cj+a}{j}],a<0\wedge -1\le b<0\wedge k=1 \wedge j\neq0
\\ [\frac{cj-a}{j},\frac{cj+a}{j}],a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge b<-1\wedge k=1 \wedge j\neq0
\\ [c,c],b\in\mathbb{N},a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge k>1 \wedge j\neq0
\\ \vdots
\\ (-\infty,\infty),a\in\mathbb{R}\wedge b\in\mathbb{N},k\in\mathbb{R},j=0
\end{array}\right.$$

There could be more, but I didn't prove them yet and it's already getting too complicated for me to guess the formula, so I would stop here for now..

Reconsider the question
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)(x-2)^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}=
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)}{(n^2+11)}(\frac{1}{7})^n(x-2)^n$$
For first part only consider the power of $n$
$$\frac{(n+4)}{(n^2+11)}\text{ power of $n$ is $-1$}$$
It would have same interval of convergence as following
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1}(\frac{1}{7})^n(x-2)^n$$

Use formula $3.$ Since $a=7,b=-1,c=2$, we can conclude that:
$$\text{interval of convergence is }[c-a,c+a)=[-5,9)$$

---

But again, I didn't prove them yet, so there could be counter examples.. please tell me if there is any books talked about this.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.

Comment: You are aware that the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$ is just the largest $r$ such that $R < r \implies \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n R^n = 0$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by writing $y=x-2$ so that the series is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+4)y^n}{7^n(n^2+11)}$$  Then 
$${a_{n+1}\over a_n}=\frac17{n+5\over n+4}{{n^2+11}\over (n+1)^2+11}\to\frac17 \text{ as } n\to\infty$$ so the radius of convergence is $7$, and the interior of the interval is $(-5,9)$.  There is no need to do all that calculation; surely you recognize by now that those fractions go to $1$, and I should think your teacher expects you to.

The series diverges at $x=9$ by the limit comparison test, but again you are doing a lot more than is needed.  Just note that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {{n+4\over n^2+11}\over \frac1n}=1$$ and you are done.

I wouldn't bother memorizing any formulas.  Your basic conclusions are correct.  Good job. The important thing is the coefficients, and when you have a rational function, what matters is the difference between the degree of the numerator and the degree of the denominator.